# display images with different z-index, change z-index on hover

Tags: php, html, css

First my idea:

In this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoNq5.png) we have 7 images that have different z-index (black has -1 and 
white has -7). Their left-padding also increases with 25px per image.
What I want now is to change the z-index of the image on hover.

Here's my code:

```html
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=7;$i++){
$p = 25 * $i;
?>
<div style="z-index: - <?php echo $i;?>;  padding-left:<?php echo $p;?>px;  position:absolute;">
<img src="images/<?php echo $i; ?>.png" />
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

This doesn't seem to work because I can't add :hover in the style attribute. Anyone has any idea how this might work?

If the z-index cannot be changed that easy on hover, then changing the width and the height of the image would also do (for example from 40x40 to 60x60).

Comment: You need javascript for the `on hover` part. Roughly it would look something like this `$('#image_id').on('hover', function(){ $(this).css("z-index", "<value>")});`. Note, I'm using jQuery here.

Comment: Make a css class or id.

Comment: Thanks a lot I made it work with jQuery.